# Mysql alias column not found in where condition

Tags: mysql

I alias a formula in a new column by the name of 'radial', I have no idea why I faced with this error "Unknown column 'radial' in 'where clause'".

```
select `id`,(sqrt(pow(`x`,2)+pow(`y`,2))) AS `radial` FROM `wdata` where `fieldtype` = 3 and `occupied` = 0 AND `x`>0 AND `y`<0 AND `radial`>$minafstand AND `radial`<$maxafstand ORDER BY rand()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct.  You cannot use column aliases in the `where` clause.  MySQL has an extension where you can put them in `having` instead:

```
select `id`,(sqrt(pow(`x`,2)+pow(`y`,2))) AS `radial`
FROM `wdata`
where `fieldtype` = 3 and `occupied` = 0 AND `x`>0 AND `y`<0
having `radial`>$minafstand AND `radial` < $maxafstand
ORDER BY rand();
```

This is quite specific to MySQL, and works as expected when the query is not doing aggregation.  Otherwise, you would need to use a subquery.

Comment: @ichimaru . . . You should elaborate and explain the issue.  Given that you are not the OP, you may misunderstand the question.